# Concurrent access to a database with Entity Framework == EntityException

Tags: sql, multithreading, wcf, entity-framework, concurrency

I've a MS SQL 2008 database which is accessed through LINQ for data update/retrival.

My linq is accessed by WCF services in a PerCall instantiation mode for an heavy application. This application has several thread which makes calls to the service, and several application are running in the sametime.

I've often some EntityException happening:

> System.Data.EntityException was caught
>     Message=An error occurred while starting a transaction on the provider connection. See the inner exception for details.
>     Source=System.Data.Entity
>     StackTrace:
>          at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.BeginDbTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
>          at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.BeginTransaction()
>          at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
>          at Infoteam.GfK.TOMServer.DataServer.DataServer.SaveChanges() in D:\Workspace\XYZWASDF\DataServer\DataServer.cs:line 123
>     InnerException: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
>          Message=Une nouvelle transaction n'est pas autorisée parce que d'autres threads sont en cours d'exécution dans la session.
>          Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
>          ErrorCode=-2146232060
>          Class=16
>          LineNumber=1
>          Number=3988
>          Procedure=""
>          Server=ift-srv114
>          State=1
>          StackTrace:
>               at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>               at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>               at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
>               at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
>               at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteTransactionManagerRequest(Byte[] buffer, TransactionManagerRequestType request, String transactionName, TransactionManagerIsolationLevel isoLevel, Int32 timeout, SqlInternalTransaction transaction, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
>               at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransactionYukon(TransactionRequest transactionRequest, String transactionName, IsolationLevel iso, SqlInternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
>               at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransaction(TransactionRequest transactionRequest, String name, IsolationLevel iso, SqlInternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
>               at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.BeginSqlTransaction(IsolationLevel iso, String transactionName)
>               at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel iso)
>               at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.BeginDbTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
>               at System.Data.Common.DbConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
>               at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.BeginDbTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
>          InnerException:

(Sorry it's not very readable). (The message of the internal exception mean "A new transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session."

I've check, I'm not in a loop, it's purely random when it makes this exception, and I've no idea about how to avoid this.

any help will be really appreciated :)

Thank you!

EDIT: Here is an example of where I got this exception SOMETIMES

```
    //My DataServer method, which is a singleton

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
            public void SaveChanges()
            {
                lock (_lockObject)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        _context.SaveChanges(SaveOptions.AcceptAllChangesAfterSave);
                        _changeListener.ManageIDAfterInsert();                       
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Logger.Instance.Error("[DataServer:SaveChanges] Got an error when trying to save an object", ex);
                        //HERE I've this error
                    }
                }
            }

//One example where I can have exception sometimes, this is called through a WCF service, so I have a method which attach the object and then save it
private OrderStatus AddOrderStatus(OrderStatus orderStatus)
        {
            DataServer.DataServer.Instance.InsertOrUpdateDetachedObject(orderStatus);

            return orderStatus;
        }
```

Comment: Can you show the code causing this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without seeing your code, the short answer is that EntityFramework is not thread-safe.  You're getting this error in a seemingly random pattern when two+ threads overlap when trying to try access your `ObjectContext`.    I assume you've stuffed your context into a `static` variable.   Either make the context a local variable or write locking around access to the `ObjectContext`.

If you want a more specific answer posting your code will help.

**Edit**

Your issue is that two threads are trying to use the context at the same time, or 1 thread is leaving a transaction open then and a second thread comes through trying to use your singleton context.  Your code snippet raises more questions for me than I had before.

- In your code example is _`lockObject` a static variable?
- Why do you show the lock in `SaveChanges` but then explain an error is being thrown
  from `InsertOrUpdateDetachedObject`?  Can we see the code for  `InsertOrUpdateDetachedObject`?
- Does SaveChanges use the same  `_lockObject` as all other methods that access the context directly?
- Is your call to `_context.SaveChanges` the only way you save to the DB or do you have other areas that open transaction contexts on their own?
- Your using a singleton so your context is shared across multiple calls. It might be preferable to instantiate a new new context for every WFC call.

Comment: I've added an example where I get some crashes sometimes. My DataServer which create the dataserver is a singleton, but I suppose that because I've a PerCall instantiation that differents call have not the same context

Comment: Hi I did not get the answer from above. could you please clear it for me?